# Severe error visiting Stack Exchange from China at 13:48 UTC, 28 Jun 2017

Tags: support, error-message, server

Time: From 13:48 UTC (Local time: 21:48 CST, aka GMT+8) and ended at 14:03 UTC

Network Environment: Everything else OK, but slow on SE and even receiving error messages.

When trying to visit several Stack Exchange sites, I frequently receive a blank page with the only text saying

> ```
> socket create error
> ```

The frequency is highly unstable. i.e. I may receive several such messages in a row right after a minute's absence of error.

Later that error was gone and got replaced by a new one saying

> [image: Error page]

And I'm logged out of SE without any notice. When trying to log back in, SE gave several "suspicious action" messages and required CAPTCHA several times before approving my login.

What happened to SE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened:

> [image]

https://twitter.com/fastly/status/880070092716769282

---

We use [Fastly](https://www.fastly.com/) for several different things (CDN, global proxy provider), and this incident is likely what you have experienced.

Comment: I see. It looks like so.